# How to keep a local cache of data from firebase when offline?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In using firebase as our backend database we are looking for a way to keep a local cache of data from when connection is interrupted. I have looked at the documentation here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities

This illustrates how to detect whether or not you are connected to the firebase backend, but it doesn't show how to keep a local cache of data when offline. I see there are native methods when using iOS or Android SDKs but is there nothing comparable for the Web/JS SDK?

Comment: If you interact with the database (eg, `firebase.database().ref('test').set('test value')`) but the app is offline, the write is automatically cached by the Firebase SDK. Your subscriptions will still trigger due to writes made locally. When the app reconnects, it will 'catch up'.

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database does not support persisting data between page reloads. If you need that, I'd recommend looking at Cloud Firestore.